# Find easter on any given year

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime

To find the days off for our custom accounting software there is this method used to find when is Easter in any given year.

```
private static DateTime Easter(int year) {
    int a = year%19;
    int b = year/100;
    int c = (b - (b/4) - ((8*b + 13)/25) + (19*a) + 15)%30;
    int d = c - (c/28)*(1 - (c/28)*(29/(c + 1))*((21 - a)/11));
    int e = d - ((year + (year/4) + d + 2 - b + (b/4))%7);
    int month = 3 + ((e + 40)/44);
    int day = e + 28 - (31*(month/4));
    return new DateTime(year, month , day);
}
```

Comment: Man, that's a lot of magic numbers. I don't even know where to start reviewing other than that.

Comment: Some comments and more descriptive variable names would help, too.

Comment: more information about what formula you are using would also be helpful in giving a good review of your code.

Comment: What about years 2000?

Comment: @paparazzo According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dates_for_Easter), it was on April 23th, the function returns the same result.

Comment: I know "This is how other people do it" is not the done thing here, but it seems worth referencing this SO thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510383/how-can-i-calculate-what-date-good-friday-falls-on-given-a-year

I especially like the comment by  Gordon Broom: "One method that has been used historically is table lookup -- don't discount this method"

Comment: Just FYI, this appears to be similar to the calculations given in various computer languages at the bottom of this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus

Comment: @Dain Ironfoot III: Well, isn't the date of Easter DEFINED by a lot of magic numbers?  And worse, different sects apparently have different ways of computing it, so there may be different days that are "Easter" depending on which one you respect: https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/determining-easter-date.html

Comment: You could fix the formatting (add spaces around `%`, `/` and `*`) and test it with the last 50 years and the next 50 years.

Comment: I got a similar algorithm for calculating easter from [cpearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/easter.aspx), who again got it from the [US Naval Observatory](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/easter.php)

Comment: Companies merge and code gets sold or given away. State which branch(es) of Christianity this code applies to, and the year when such application is valid, because branches of Christianity are subject to change too. State a book this algorithm appears in; web pages go dark.

Comment: You appear to have forgotten [leap centuries](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_leap_year)

Comment: I think this may be quite literally the formula that Gauss developed, which is the official method. The alternative is going deep into astronomy and calculating the path of the moon around the earth for the next few hundred years.

Answer (score 47):

The usual advice is "make meaningful variables". However, we know this algorithm (essentially a modification of that published by a young Gauß) and those variables don't have a simple meaning. (See [Decoding Gauss Easter algorithm](//math.stackexchange.com/q/896954)). We know `b` represents centuries, but even if you did find a word to describe what the variables represent, would using `epact` or even `ageOfMoonOnJanFirst` help to understand the algorithm? The variable represent stages of the algorithm. As Gauss wrote "It is not possible to present the full analysis that led to the algorithm".

So the usual cure of incomprehensible code - clear variables names - won't help much here.  What can we do for the poor person who has to maintain this code 6 months, or 6 years, later?  We can let them know where this algorithm comes from. This is easy enough. A comment referencing the source would allow someone seeing this to check that it is still doing what it is supposed to do.

Beyond adding this comment, the algorithm for calculating Easter is unlikely to be a bottleneck in any piece of software, so assuming that this algorithm is correct (proven and tested) I would leave it as is.

Comment: "A comment referencing the source..." - do not forget add algorithm name (Gauss Easter algorithm), sources tend to vanish.

Comment: I think that adding proper names **helps** but if variables match an available public paper/document (which you correctly suggest to link/include) then it does not really matter. HOWEVER, to **split** that long cryptic formula **in multiple small functions** (which may - or not - be reusable elsewhere) may surely help to at least vaguely understand the algorithm. It's our _duty_ as programmers to make code as easy to understand as possible (especially when we spent maybe one hour to study an algorithm...we/they don't want to do it again and again each time we look at it)

Answer (score 15):

When I finish writing code, I usually ask myself : *"Okay, do I think I'd be able to understand my code in six months?"*

If the answer is no, it means I'm not done. My code needs to be clearer.

I 100% think I wouldn't understand your code in six months as I don't get it now.

### Naming

Crudely put, the variable names are terrible. What does `a,b,c,d,e` mean? Why is 19, 11, 21, etc there?

As I said above, I don't understand your code so I can't propose better names, but you should name your variables accordingly to what they do **and** use variables for all those "magic numbers". "Six months in the future" yourself might thank you if there's a bug in the code.

I'd also rename the method to `GetEasterDate`.

Comment: What would be the value of naming the method “GetEasterDate” ?  – It is private static, so it is well documented enough to the class implementor is just a computation (not a state change).

Comment: @MichaelLeBarbierGrünewald I'm not sure I understand your point. Because it is private static, it is well documented enough?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to understand this *one day* after.

Answer (score 10):

The code itself is fine. Computing the Easter date is an astronomical computation and it is not possible to make it easier to understand without actually adding a full demonstration about why it yields the correct result.

Since this is an accounting software I would consider the given level of (no) details fine.  I would however increase the capacity of the maintenance programmer to ensure that the code is correct by ensure that:

1. The method used has a traceable origin. AFAICT the computation implements the algorithm described by [Claus Tøndering](https://www.tondering.dk/claus/cal/easter.php) in his classical Calendar FAQ. (See Isn’t there a simpler way to calculate Easter?)  The source should be referenced in the code, *e.g.* “Compute Easter day à la https://www.tondering.dk/claus/cal/easter.php”.  If you are only interested by the modern era (post 1920) it is not worth mentioning the algorithm works only for the Gregorian calendar.
2. The variables used in your implementation match as closely as possible those used in the source, to ease verification.  (Which is not the case here, but you might have a better source for this purpose than I had.)
3. Besides the snippet above, there is unit tests for this computation.

Comment: The algorithm is a bit older than that. [This page](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/easter.php) sources it to J.M. Oudin in 1940.

Comment: Oudin is also quoted on the page from Claus Tøndering: I cited the page as a possible reference for documenting the computation implemented, but there are probably a lot of other plausible choices.