# Bar graph of Easter date distribution

Tags: c, datetime, reinventing-the-wheel, data-visualization, c99

Computing Easter for a given year is a classic computational problem.

It is also one of the few cases when code seems to just have to live with [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Alternative to magic numbers: [Decoding Gauss' Easter Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/896954/83175)

So I thought [today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notre-Dame_de_Paris#2019_Fire), I'd do something positive and make an Easter bar graph.

**C99 Review goal: General coding comments, style, etc.**

```
// easter.h
// chux: April 15, 2019

#ifndef EASTER_H
#define EASTER_H

#define EASTER_EPOCH_YEAR 33
#define EASTER_JULIAN_YEAR EASTER_EPOCH_YEAR
#define EASTER_GREGORIAN_EPOCH_YEAR 1582 /* 15 October 1582 */
#define EASTER_JULIAN_PERIOD 532
#define EASTER_GREGORIAN_PERIOD 5700000

typedef struct ymd {
  int y, m, d;
} ymd;

ymd Easter_DateJulian(int year);
ymd Easter_DateGregorian(int year);
ymd Easter_Date(int year);

#endif

// easter.c

/*
 * Anonymous Gregorian algorithm: Meeus/Jones/Butcher
 *  * Dates of Easter
 * Astronomical Algorithms 1991
 * Jean Meeus
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus#Anonymous_Gregorian_algorithm
 * 
 * Meeus's Julian algorithm
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computus#Meeus's_Julian_algorithm
 */
ymd Easter_DateJulian(int year) {
  if (year < EASTER_EPOCH_YEAR) {
    return (ymd) {0, 0, 0};
  }
  int a = year % 4;
  int b = year % 7;
  int c = year % 19;
  int d = (19 * c + 15) % 30;
  int e = (2 * a + 4 * b - d + 34) % 7;
  int f = (d + e + 114) / 31;
  int g = (d + e + 114) % 31;
  return (ymd) {year, f, g + 1};
}

ymd Easter_DateGregorian(int year) {
  if (year <= EASTER_GREGORIAN_EPOCH_YEAR) {
    return (ymd) {0, 0, 0};
  }
  int a = year%19;
  int b = year/100;
  int c = year%100;
  int d = b/4;
  int e = b%4;
  int f = (b+8)/25;
  int g = (b-f+1)/3;
  int h = (19*a + b - d - g + 15)%30;
  int i = c/4;
  int k = c%4;
  int l = (32 + 2*e + 2*i - h - k)%7;
  int m = (a+11*h + 22*l) / 451;
  int n = (h + l - 7 *m + 114)/31;
  int p = (h + l - 7 *m + 114)%31;
  return (ymd) {year, n, p+1};
}

ymd Easter_Date(int year) {
  return (year > EASTER_GREGORIAN_EPOCH_YEAR) ?
      Easter_DateGregorian(year) : Easter_DateJulian(year);
}
```

Test

```
// main.c

// **Alternate code used as a check**
// Find easter on any given year
// https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193847/find-easter-on-any-given-year
// Decoding Gauss' Easter Algorithm
// https://math.stackexchange.com/q/896954/83175

static ymd Easter(int year) {
    int a = year%19;
    int b = year/100;
    int c = (b - (b/4) - ((8*b + 13)/25) + (19*a) + 15)%30;
    int d = c - (c/28)*(1 - (c/28)*(29/(c + 1))*((21 - a)/11));
    int e = d - ((year + (year/4) + d + 2 - b + (b/4))%7);
    int month = 3 + ((e + 40)/44);
    int day = e + 28 - (31*(month/4));
    return (ymd) {year, month , day};
}

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int count[5][32] = { 0 };
  for (int year = EASTER_GREGORIAN_EPOCH_YEAR + 1;
      year <= EASTER_GREGORIAN_EPOCH_YEAR + EASTER_GREGORIAN_PERIOD;
      year++) {
    ymd e1 = Easter_Date(year);
    ymd e2 = Easter(year);
    if (e1.d != e2.d) {
      printf("%5d-%02d-%02d ", e1.y, e1.m, e1.d);
      printf("%5d-%02d-%02d ", e2.y, e2.m, e2.d);
      puts("");
    }
    assert(e1.m >= 3 && e1.m <=4);
    assert(e1.d >= 1 && e1.d <=31);
    count[e1.m][e1.d]++;
  }
  for (int m = 3; m <= 4; m++) {
    for (int d = 1; d <= 31; d++) {
      if (count[m][d]) {
        double permill =  round(1000.0*count[m][d]/EASTER_GREGORIAN_PERIOD);
        printf("%d, %2d, %3.1f%%, %0*d\n", m, d, permill/10, (int) permill, 0);
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output: Month, Day, Percentage, Graph

```
3, 22, 0.5%, 00000
3, 23, 1.0%, 0000000000
3, 24, 1.4%, 00000000000000
3, 25, 1.9%, 0000000000000000000
3, 26, 2.3%, 00000000000000000000000
3, 27, 2.9%, 00000000000000000000000000000
3, 28, 3.3%, 000000000000000000000000000000000
3, 29, 3.4%, 0000000000000000000000000000000000
3, 30, 3.3%, 000000000000000000000000000000000
3, 31, 3.3%, 000000000000000000000000000000000
4,  1, 3.4%, 0000000000000000000000000000000000
4,  2, 3.3%, 000000000000000000000000000000000
4,  3, 3.4%, 0000000000000000000000000000000000
4,  4, 3.3%, 000000000000000000000000000000000
4,  5, 3.4%, 0000000000000000000000000000000000
4,  6, 3.3%, 000000000000000000000000000000000
4,  7, 3.3%, 000000000000000000000000000000000
4,  8, 3.4%, 0000000000000000000000000000000000
4,  9, 3.3%, 000000000000000000000000000000000
4, 10, 3.4%, 0000000000000000000000000000000000
4, 11, 3.3%, 000000000000000000000000000000000
4, 12, 3.4%, 0000000000000000000000000000000000
4, 13, 3.3%, 000000000000000000000000000000000
4, 14, 3.3%, 000000000000000000000000000000000
4, 15, 3.4%, 0000000000000000000000000000000000
4, 16, 3.3%, 000000000000000000000000000000000
4, 17, 3.4%, 0000000000000000000000000000000000
4, 18, 3.5%, 00000000000000000000000000000000000
4, 19, 3.9%, 000000000000000000000000000000000000000
4, 20, 3.3%, 000000000000000000000000000000000  <-- 2019
4, 21, 2.9%, 00000000000000000000000000000
4, 22, 2.4%, 000000000000000000000000
4, 23, 1.9%, 0000000000000000000
4, 24, 1.5%, 000000000000000
4, 25, 0.7%, 0000000
```

Comment: Can you clarify what percentage means here? Percentage of  what?

Comment: @user1118321 True " percentage" lacks specific context.  It is the percentage of occurrence.  The values sum to 100.0%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice work! Here are my comments, mostly style related:

`easter.h:`

- Consider using `#pragma once` instead of the classic style header guard. While it's not strictly-conforming C, it's supported by all mainstream compilers. It is of my personal preference, since it keeps code cleaner and more uniform.

  For further discussions, pros and cons:

  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard
  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once

`easter.c:`

- `#include "easter.h"` is missing.
- In `Easter_DateGregorian`, variables `n` and `p` could be renamed `month` and `day`, respectively. While this knowledge could be implied from the return statement, it's better to give them a meaningful name. Then, the `+ 1` should be added to `day`, instead of when returning.
- Similarly, in `Easter_DateJulian`, `f` and `g` could be renamed `month` and day, respectively.

`main.c:`

- `#include "easter.h"` is missing.
- The function `Easter` appears before the `#include`s block: my recommendation is always placing `#include`s at the very beginning of the source file. It is useful to know that includes are always found in the same place, and not hiding in the source code. Also, since `Easter` is a reference function, consider a more expressive name such as `Easter_Ref`.
- `#include <math.h>` is missing for `round.h`.
- Since `count` is a two-dimentional array, it should be initialized with double braces: `int count[5][32] = { { 0 } };`.
- Consider using named constants for months 3 and 4, such as `MARCH` and `APRIL`. That way, the meaning of `m` is clear immediately.
- From the same reasoning, consider renaming `m` and `d` to `month` and `day` respectively.